# Strange result using NIntegrate with Max and PDF

Tags: numerical-integration

This is really trivial and I appologise in advance if I have made a stupid error somewhere. I have been chasing down some strange results when using `NIntegrate` with integrands involving `Max` and `PDF`. A simple example follows.

```
f[x1_, x2_] := PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, .5}, {.5, 1}}], {x1, x2}];
NIntegrate[Max[Exp[x1] + Exp[x2] - 3, 0] f[x1, x2],
 {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

This gave the answer 0.804628. However, when I tried MATLAB I got 1.2255. So I then used Monte Carlo.

```
Block[{rho = 0.5, data, rv1, rv2, paths = 1000000, sum, sumSquared, mean, var, stdError},
 data = Table[
   rv1 = Random[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
   rv2 = rho rv1 + Sqrt[1 - rho^2] Random[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
   Max[Exp[rv1] + Exp[rv2] - 3, 0], {i, paths}];
 sum = Total[data];
 sumSquared = Total[data^2];
 mean = sum/paths;
 var = (sumSquared/paths - mean^2) paths/(paths - 1);
 stdError = Sqrt[var/paths];
 {mean, stdError}
]
```

One run of this gave {1.22509, 0.0031105}, agreeing with the MATLAB result. I have also noticed that if I replace `Max[Exp[rv1] + Exp[rv2] - 3, 0]` with `Exp[rv1] + Exp[rv2] - 3` the issue does not arise. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: You can consider reporting these cases to support at wolfram.com.

Comment: @Szabolcs, as shown in the answer below it is possible to obtain the correct answer by fiddling with the options of NIntegrate, but I must admit I am very surprised that this is necessary in such a simple case.

Comment: I don't know if it's reasonable to call this a bug or not, but I may have accepted this result as a valid answer without checking because the integrand is so simple (it's relatively smooth). (Observation: if the integration bounds are not infinite, then you get a correct result.) I'd say that it's a bit dangerous to get bad results *with no warnings* in simple cases like this. Mathematica tends to get warnings if the integration doesn't converge. So I think it is worth reporting this problem to support, and they'll decide if the situation can be improved or not. Please report it if you can.

Comment: Yet another indicator that this may be a bug: if I use the option `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`, I get the correct result (although with a warning about slow convergence).

Comment: I've been sitting here worrying about the same thing - why no warning from Mathematica? Also, on reflection, I may have been a little hasty in accepting the answer. I think I will report this - do you know where I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[x1_, x2_] := 
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, .5}, {.5, 1}}], {x1, x2}];

NIntegrate[ Max[Exp[x1] + Exp[x2] - 3, 0] f[x1, x2], {x2, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, MinRecursion -> 2,  MaxRecursion -> 5]

(* 1.22555 *)
```

`NIntgrate` will complain about convergence, tinker with `AccuracyGoal` and precision options as desired if the warning is bothersome. Note also the precision of your arguments...

Edit - upping `MaxRecursion` to 20 in this example converges without warning to 1.22554.